# Service Area: Multiple network locations per facility

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, service-area

I am generating service areas using ArcMap's Ready-To-Use Services. I'm Using ArcMap 10.3. I am doing walking distance to train stations using 500m 1000m and 1500m.

I manage to create the service areas, but I find the locations (train stations in this case) snap to only one point on the network. This results in the service area being created only on one side of the train line (the side where the road is closer) despite being able to access from both sides in reality (see example below).

[image: train station example]

Is there a way to make the location snap to more than one road on the network without adding points manually (I have many train and bus stations that I am doing this with)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user please take the [Tour]. Please [edit] your question to include the options you set in Network Analyst that were used to trace the network.  Some screenshots of the different options tabs might be useful too.